# Multipart form submission does not work over SSL HTTP2 on Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, multipartform-data

The SSL Connector configuration in server.xml (Tomcat 9) is given below

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"  maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">  
<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
<SSLHostConfig honorCipherOrder="false" >  
    <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/toeflssl.key"  
    certificateFile="conf/2_toeflmadeeasy.com.crt"  
    certificateChainFile="conf/1_Intermediate.crt"  />  
</SSLHostConfig>
```

Multipart form submission does not work (the form variable values are not retrieved on server in the servlet)  with above connector. With only one change (removal of the line `<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />`) it works. But now I am not on HTTP2. Anyone have any ideas how I can get it to work on  HTTP2.

The sample multipart form html code is given below

```
<form name="multiPartForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" id="form_submission_type" name="form_submission_type" value="submitTestMultipart">
<input type="hidden" id="var1" name="var1" value="a">
<input type="hidden" id="var2" name="var2" value="b">
File 1:<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" size="20" value=""><font size="2"></font>
<br>
File 2:<input type="file" id="file2" name="file2" size="20" value=""><font size="2"></font>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" name="submitBtnMP1" onClick="javascript:submitTestMultipartForm();">
<br>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions and comments.

Comment: Do both HTTP2 and TLS work, aside from the upload problems? How big of a file are you trying to upload?

Comment: Yes both HTTP2 and  TLS work. The multipart form (file uploads) submits do not work.

Comment: ...and how big of a file are you trying to upload?

Comment: It is very small less than 1 MB.

Comment: Has anyone configured TLS on Tomcat 9 over HTTP2 and had the multipart form submits work? I could try to use the same configuration.

Comment: Consider posting to the Tomcat user mailing list if you think you've found a bug. h2 is still very new in Tomcat.

Comment: Christopher thanks for the suggestion. I subscribed to the Tomcat mailing list and have sent an email to users-help@tomcat.apache.org.

Comment: Still do not have a solution to my problem. The posting on Tomcat mailing list did not help. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Wrong e-mail address. You need to post to users@tomcat.apache.org

Comment: I am seeing this same problem with the first release of Tomcat 8.5 BETA

Comment: I have not been able to resolve the issue. Hoping someone would help out. I have given up using HTTP2 for the time being. I used Tomcat 9 m4 and Spring Framework..